# How do I make a control blend file that can link to other blend files and save changes from the control to the external blend files?

Tags: blend-files

I would like to add props, sets, and characters from external .blend files into a main .blend file scene but have it save to the external .blend files, rather than append which copys the files or link which gives me very few options to change the objects.

Answer (score 1):

The answer I was looking for was Make Proxy. After linking an object, on that object, It's Object > Make Proxy or Ctl+Alt+P.